# Create Google Spreadsheet in folder swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a google spreadsheet in a specific folder using the google drive/sheets api.

My code so far which creates a spreadsheet in the root of the google drive.

```
let newSheet = GTLRSheets_Spreadsheet.init()
let properties = GTLRSheets_SpreadsheetProperties.init()

properties.title = name
newSheet.properties = properties

let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsCreate.query(withObject:newSheet)
query.fields = "spreadsheetId"

query.completionBlock = { (ticket, result, NSError) in

    if let error = NSError {

    }
    else {
        let response = result as! GTLRSheets_Spreadsheet
        let identifier = response.spreadsheetId
        completion!(true,nil,identifier)
    }
}
service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: nil)
```

I can't see any properties on the query or GTLRSheets to set the parent folder or url.  Any help ould be great. Thanks

Comment: [Check this google doc](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ios)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the JSON string with the inherited `JSONString` method and save this.

```
let JSON = newSheet.JSONString()
JSON.write(toFile:…,automically:…, encoding:…) // or whatever method to write
```

Comment: How do you mean sorry, could you give me an example